# How to handle non equally-sized data frames

Tags: r, dplyr, across

In dplyr/across, below code show error "...defined for equally-sized data frames". This caused by  no `profit_2023` to match with existing variable `profit_2022`.How to handle it ?(I want the no match the result and return NA or blank)

```
library(tidyverse)

raw_data_2 <- data.frame(category=c('A','B','C'),
                       sales_2022=c(1,2,3),
                       profit_2022=c(0.1,0.4,0.3),
                       margin_2022=c(0.2,0.8,0.6),
                       sales_2023=c(1.5,3,4),
                       margin_2023=c(0.3,0.7,0.5)
                       )

raw_data_2 %>% mutate((across(contains("_2023"),.names="{col}_increase") / across(contains("_2022"))-1))
```

Comment: Can you provide the logic and an example of the intended outcome?  It's not clear from your question.

Comment: You should either create a new variable profit_2023 with only NAs, or remove it from your selection in `across(contains(...))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue with your data is that it's quite untidy. Clean the data, and it becomes a lot more straightforward:

```
raw_data_2 |>
  pivot_longer(cols = -category, names_to = c(".value", "year"), names_sep = "_") |> 
  mutate(across(c(sales, profit, margin), \(x) x/lag(x)-1, .names = "{.col}_increase"), .by = category)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 8
  category year  sales profit margin sales_increase profit_increase
  <chr>    <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>          <dbl>           <dbl>
1 A        2022    1      0.1    0.2         NA                  NA
2 A        2023    1.5   NA      0.3          0.5                NA
3 B        2022    2      0.4    0.8         NA                  NA
4 B        2023    3     NA      0.7          0.5                NA
5 C        2022    3      0.3    0.6         NA                  NA
6 C        2023    4     NA      0.5          0.333              NA
# ℹ 1 more variable: margin_increase <dbl>
```

Notes:

1. Untidy data is hard to use, and narrows your options until you're forced into doing things the jankiest way possible. There's a bunch of reasons why keeping your data tidy is a good idea (you can find many [here](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html)), but maybe the best one is your own sanity!
2. The profit increase column is all NAs, because the 2023 profit rows are all NAs, and there is no one prior to 2022, so the 2022 ones are NAs also.